# Adding string and int as hexadecimal

Tags: c#, hex, decimal

I want to add two hexadecimal numbers in hex mode and result should also be hexadecimal.
But the problem is I have a string "20010000" and int 0x400050, how should I add those to receive 0x20410050 ?

Ive tried int.Parse with various hex options but it always results as decimal addition.

Comment: Can you share some variable declarations? Is it `string foo = "20010000"; int bar = 0x400050;`? If so, I think your question is just "How do I parse a string as a hexadecimal number?" Right?

Comment: how to add bar to foo like both were hex and receive hex number.
Its more like "How to parse string as hex but leave its value", when I were searching for solution, only "how to parse decimal string to hex int" pops up.

Comment: I'm doing a lot of guessing as to what you actually want, but see if my answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
string aString = "20010000";
int a = Convert.ToInt32(aString, 16); // should be 536936448
int b = 0x400050; // should be 4194384

int sum = a + b; // should be 541130832
string sumString = sum.ToString("X"); // should be "20410050"
string sumStringWithPrefix = "0x" + subString; // should be "0x20410050"
```

Comment: Thats what Ive been looking for, was trying something simillar before but for some reason it doesnt works. Thanks for your reply